# Split table into related tables based on regex pattern matching of a text column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assuming we have a table of products where each vendor has a slightly different name for the same product. What's the best way to split the table using regex pattern matching to identify our similar strings.

See the following example:

```
p_id     p_name            cat           start_time     vendor              attrs
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     'iphone'            'phones'      some date       'google'        some_jsonb
2     'apple iphone'      'phones'      some date       'ebay'           some_other_jsonb
```

Wanted result:

```
table A
p_id    p_name 
1      'iphone'

table B
e_id    p_ref    vendor            attrs
1        1      'google'     some_jsonb
2        1      'ebay'       some_other_jsonb
```

My problem is not with the regex rule or splitting the tables into two related tables, but where and how to implement my regex rule to find the duplication in the column p_name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for each `p_name`, you want the shortest subname that is already in the table, then you can use logic like this:

```
select e.p_name
from example e
where not exists (select 1
                  from example e2
                  where e.p_name like '%' || e2.p_name || '%' and
                        e.p_name <> e2.pname
                 );
```